# ListView doesn't update on returning to the activity

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I am working on one app and I have one list view in one screen in that i am passing values using class. On `listview`'s item click event it opens activity for selecting values. and i m saving this value to the `SharedPrefrence` as i wanted these data to the another activity. It stores value to the `SharedPreference`. But it doesnt update `listview` on returning to the activity. But I am getting updated List `onCreate()`.

```
try{
            selectedParentMessage = ParentMessageListActivity.parentMsgSharedPref.getString("SelectedParentMessage", "None");

            System.out.println("Selected Parent Message:"+selectedParentMessage);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        items.add(new Setting_ActivitySectionItem("Sounds"));
        //items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Cartoon's Voice", ""));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Record Parent's Message", ""+selectedParentMessage));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Import Lullaby", ""));


        items.add(new Setting_ActivitySectionItem("Alerts"));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Phone Number", ""));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Email Id", ""));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Send Notification", ""));
        //items.add(new EntryItem("Item 7", "This is item 2.4"));

        items.add(new Setting_ActivitySectionItem("Baby's Noise Level"));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("High", ""));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Medium", ""));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Low", ""));
        //items.add(new EntryItem("Item 11", "This is item 3.4"));
        //items.add(new EntryItem("Item 12", "This is item 3.5"));

        items.add(new Setting_ActivitySectionItem("Set Auto-silent"));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Auto Silent", ""));

        items.add(new Setting_ActivitySectionItem("Set Battery reminder"));
        items.add(new Setting_ActivityEntryItem("Battery Reminder", ""));

        adapter = new Setting_ActivityEntryAdapter(this, items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and also i am applying `notifydatasetchange()` on `onResume` and `onRestart()`

```
public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        System.out.println("onrestart");
        try{
            selectedParentMessage = ParentMessageListActivity.parentMsgSharedPref.getString("SelectedParentMessage", "None");

            System.out.println("Selected Parent Message:"+selectedParentMessage);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        getListView().invalidateViews();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and same for `onPause()`

Comment: Are you re-reading your preferences in `onResume()`?

Comment: yes. i m re-reading value.

Comment: I didn't get you. What exactly is the requirement?

Comment: i have Two activities. On First Activity i have custom listview its like "Title" and "value" and another is the one from which i store values to the sharedpreference and that sharedpreference value i want to show in 1st activitiy's listview when i return to that listview activity. I am getting value for "value" only on onCreate().

Comment: Will you please add the complete code in question, i can't see the SharedPreference and its usage in your code.

Comment: @Saurabh please specify the correct answer if it is not one of the answers suggested below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
        adapter.clear();
        addItem();
    }
```

`addItem()` is function which will add list items to the class and generate the adapter and set the listview.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new instance of the adapter using the same variable you used in your adapter and set the adapter on the list again.

Try this on onResume:

```
adapter = new Setting_ActivityEntryAdapter(this, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

call it `yourlistView.invalidateViews();`

Try this .

```
ListAdapter la = listView.getAdapter();
                        if( la != null){
                            ((BaseAdapter)la).notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
```

Comment: did you try notifydatasetchange in resume/start ?

Answer (score 0):

Do `notifydatasetchange()` for your adapter of `listview` in `onStart()`

Comment: Did you commit after you saving data in SharedPreference?